# FOREIGN KEY: contains no primary or candidate keys

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server , I got this error ->

```
  SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[PostsTags]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column
 is a computed column, it should be persisted.
```

I don't understand why dint works foreign key, without them table created without problems, but I need a relationship between tables, in this location.I looked at other similar questions, but the answers were not found.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PostsTags] (
    [PostId] INT NOT NULL,
    [TegId]  INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PostsTags] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PostId] ASC, [TegId] ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Comments] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PostId]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [Name]     NVARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
    [Body]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tags] (
    [Id]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Tags_PostsTags] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [PostsTags]([TegId]) ON DELETE CASCADE 
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Posts] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]    NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [Body]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Avtor]     NVARCHAR (64)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [Post_Tag] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [PostsTags]([PostId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [Post_Comment] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [Comments]([PostId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
```

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: This url might help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879735/there-are-no-primary-or-candidate-keys-in-the-referenced-table-that-match-the-re]

Comment: Your foreign keys in `Posts` don't make sense. How can a single column (`Posts.ID`) reference *two* different tables at the same time? I also think you want them the other way round `PostsTags references Posts` and `Comments references Posts` not the way you wrote it.

Comment: post with comments related one to many;
post tags associated with many-to-many, as you can not directly, added a table connection. This problem occurs in 2013 visual studio, in 2010 I did the same with no problems.

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name - all of these foreign keys look like you're creating them the wrong way around.

Comment: I'm trying to create a blog using Visual Studio 2013, there is a post he has tags and comments to the post, again in 2010, I did it using relationships. in 2013 no relationships. because trying to write code, seeing as it makes no. again sorry for the bad English. The fact that I do I do not doubt it, but that is how I do have errors.

Comment: I know what I want to do, but do not know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is this, I'm sure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tags] (
    [Id]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Posts] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]    NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [Body]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Avtor]     NVARCHAR (64)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PostsTags] (
    [PostId] INT NOT NULL,
    [TagId]  INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PostsTags] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
           ([PostId] ASC, [TagId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PostsTags_Tags] FOREIGN KEY ([TagId])
           REFERENCES [Tags]([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PostTags_Posts] FOREIGN KEY ([PostId])
           REFERENCES [Posts]([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE 
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Comments] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PostId]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [Name]     NVARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
    [Body]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Comments_Posts] FOREIGN KEY ([PostId])
          REFERENCES [Posts](Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

That is - you can freely insert into `Tags` or `Posts` without consideration of any other tables or data within them. *Once* there's a row in `Posts`, you can start adding rows to `Comments`, *provided* that the `PostId` column contains a value that already exists in the `Posts` table's `Id` column (`Comments` *references* `Posts`)

*Further*, once there are rows in both `Posts` and `Tags`, only then can you insert rows into `PostTags`, with again constraints on what values are valid in that table being based on current rows in `Posts` and `Tags`.

Finally, I've left your `CASCADE` options set as in your original. If someone deletes a row from `Posts` then all rows in `Comments` that relate to that post are deleted. Similarly, any rows in `PostsTags` that relate to the post are deleted. If someone deletes a row from `Tags` then all rows in `PostsTags` that references that tag are removed.