# How to alter table to create foreign keys between two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 4 tables (`Guardian`, `Child`, `Branch` and `ChildBranch`).

`Child` is weak to `Guardian`. `ChildBranch` is the weak associative entity of `Child` and `Branch`.

They all have primary keys and data.

```
Guardian Primary Key : Email (PK, FK, varChar(100), not null) 
Child Primary Key : Email (PK, FK, varChar(100), not null) 
                    FirstName (PK, varChar(50), not null) 
ChildBranch Primary Key : Email (PK, FK, varChar(100), not null) 
                          FirstName (PK, varChar(50), not null) 
                          Name (PK, varchar(50), not null)
```

How do I create the foreign key between `Child` and `ChildBranch`?

I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE ChildBranch
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Email)
REFERENCES Child(Email);
```

But got this error

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Child' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__ChildBran__Email__7B5B524B'.

I expect to create the link between the `Child` and `ChildBranch` tables.

Comment: IF you want to create a foreign key between `ChildBranch` and `Child`, then your referenced table `CHild` **must have** a primary key that **exactly** matches your FK reference. It has to be the same data type, and you cannot reference parts of a composite PK (if you have a composite PK on `Child`). Quite obviously, `Email` alone is **NOT** the PK on your `Child` table .... Show us the **complete** structure of the two tables `Child` and `ChildBranch` so we can help

Comment: Can you provide Script of the schema with keys of both tables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table that match the referencing column list in the foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879735/there-are-no-primary-or-candidate-keys-in-the-referenced-table-that-match-the-re)

Comment: You can see at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Deepest apologies i just started using stack overflow today.

Answer (score 0):

Since ChildBranch has a composite Primary key of Email and FirstName. The answer should look something like this:

ALTER TABLE ChildBranch 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Email, FirstName)
REFERENCES Child(Email, FirstName);

Thank you to all those who helped me understand this.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder FOREIGN KEY (PersonID)
    REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);

Or

ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);