# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Card' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key

Tags: sql-server, weak-entity

Create table scripts:

```
Create Table [Card]
(
    GiveDate Date not null, 
    PN nvarchar(50) not null, 
    FOREIGN KEY (PN) REFERENCES Patient (PN),
    PRIMARY KEY (GiveDate,PN)
)

Create table [Registration]
(
    EntryDate Date not null,
    ExitDate Date, 
    RoomId int not null,
    CardGiveDate date not null, 
    PN nvarchar(50) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (PN, EntryDate, CardGiveDate),
    FOREIGN KEY (PN, CardGiveDate) REFERENCES [Card](PN, GiveDate)
)
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879735/there-are-no-primary-or-candidate-keys-in-the-referenced-table-that-match-the-re) but it doesn't help me.

Card table has primary key

Comment: so should i refer PN column to other table  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PK in  `Card` is `(GiveDate, PN)` , but your FK references a key `(PN, GiveDate)`  - the  order of the columns **must match**! So try this in your `Registration` table:

```
Create table [Registration]
(
    EntryDate Date not null,
    ExitDate Date, 
    RoomId int not null,
    CardGiveDate date not null, 
    PN nvarchar(50) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (PN, EntryDate, CardGiveDate),
    -- make sure to specify the columns in the same order as they are defined in the referenced table!
    FOREIGN KEY (PN, CardGiveDate) REFERENCES [Card](GiveDate, PN)
)
```

Comment: @TariqHajeer: again , the **order of the columns** in the FK constraint **must match** the definition of the PK in the referenced table - simple as that. `FOREIGN KEY (EntryDate,CardGiveDate,PN) REFERENCES [Registration](PN, EntryDate, CardGiveDate)`