# Is there a need to add index in a column if it's already in order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To my knowledge indexes arrange items in the column to speed up the search operations, but what if the column is already ordered alphabetically, and I want to look for a name in the LastName column, does the index improve the search in this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292662/how-important-is-the-order-of-columns-in-indexes

Comment: Yes, the indexes improves the performance of a search.

Comment: Delete a row; add a row. What order do you have now?

Answer (score 3):

Only a `CLUSTERED INDEX` order the data *physically*.

Anyway you **can't rely** on the `CLUSTERED INDEX` order. Only because you "see" ordered data, it doesn't mean it will always be.

Order is guaranteed only by placing an `ORDER BY` clause in your queries.

So, if you use that column in `WHERE` clauses, creating an index for that column would speed up your queries. **But beware this really depends on several other factors.**

Answer (score 0):

All indexes except one (the Clustered index) are stored outside of the table and doesn't change the order of rows in the actual table.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between an alphabetical index on a name column and the name column being sorted alphabetically.

**Querying on an alphabetical index:**
When you run the query `SELECT LastName FROM TABLE...` the database engine will take the `LastName` you specified and enter it into an index (hashing) function.  The output of this index function tells the database exactly where to look in memory to find the record containing the `LastName`, and this lookup is extremely fast O(1).

**Querying on an alphabetically sorted LastName column *without* an index:**
When you run the same `SELECT` query as above, the database has to look through the entire table to find the record you want.  Even though the `LastName` column may be in perfect alphabetical order, the database engine won't know this, and therefore won't be able to take advantage of the order.  The lookup time will be much slower in this case for a large table.

So the answer to your question is yes, placing an index on the column will make a difference, even if all records are already alphabetically sorted on the `LastName`.

Answer (score 0):

If a column just happens to be sorted but not indexed then a search on that column will be a table scan.  Without an index the query optimizer cannot take advantage of the sorted data.