# For a composite index of columns of different cardinality, does order matter?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

For a query that uses ALL columns of a composite b-tree index

`SELECT * from customers where gender = 'M' AND date_of_birth < '2000-01-01'`

Is there a difference between

`CREATE INDEX low_then_high ON customer (gender, date_of_birth);
CREATE INDEX high_then_low ON customer (date_of_birth, gender);`

A similar question is [How to pair low/high cardinality columns as composite indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726933/how-to-pair-low-high-cardinality-columns-as-composite-indexes) but the accepted answer did not explain the reason behind the recommendation.

I am asking about MySQL but I'm guessing that the answer would apply to any b-tree index.

Comment: in each index  is better  place left side the column with higher  cardinality ..(more selective)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Cardinality in multi-column `INDEXes` does not matter.  However, the usage of the columns *does* matter.

The first column(s) in the index needs to be tested with `=`.  After that, you get one crack at a "range", such as `<` or `BETWEEN`.  `IN` is in a gray area where it sometimes optimized like `=`, sometimes like a range.

More specifically, for `where gender = 'M' AND date_of_birth < '2000-01-01'`, *cardinality does not matter*.

```
(gender, date_of_birth) -- will use both columns.
(date_of_birth, gender) -- will ignore `gender` and not be as efficient.
```

Similarly, note that the link you provided is *not* the same as your case because of `=` versus `<`.

I discuss these issues further in my [*Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .

I discuss this further in [Higher cardinality column first in an index when involving a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-range)