# Columns order in secondary index

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-performance

Assume we have table in MySql database that contains two columns `A` and `B`. And now I need to create a secondary index on them.

Question: is there any difference on how I choose order of columns in index(`A|B` or `B|A`) taking into consideration following statements:

1. I will always perform selects filtering by both columns: `WHERE A=sth AND B=sth` so there is no difference on how to choose *leftmost* part of index.
2. Values in column `B` are much more unique than values in column `A`.

Comment: If the `WHERE` is using on `=` and one 'range', see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-range

Comment: A more important question when choosing `INDEX(A,B)` over `(B,A)` is whether you also have `WHERE A=sth` without `B` or `B` is used in a range.

Comment: Be careful in reading the "dup" Q&A, there are some confusing and contradictory tips.  The important thing to note:  Cardinality is _not_ important.

Comment: @Rick James If I'm going to do only `=` searches, does the cardinality matter like in "dup"  q&a described?

Comment: Add the index, then show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and any queries using either or both of the columns.