# Simple SQL query but huge table - how to optimize?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization, where-clause

I've got this very simple MySQL query:

```
SELECT target FROM table WHERE goal_id=1 AND year>=2015 AND year<=2020
```

The table has about 5 millions rows, though. And as a result, it's very slow (about 10 seconds).

What could I do to improve things? Would an index help, and if so on which column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this query, you want the following index:

```
create index myindex on mytable(year, goal_id, target)
```

This gives you a *covering* index: all columns that come into play in the query are part of the index, so this gives the database a decent chance to execute the query by looking at the index only (without actually looking at the *data*).

The ordering of columns in the index is important: the first two columns correspond to the `where` predicates, and the last column is the column comes into play in the `select` clause.

Depending on the cardinality of your data, you might also want to try to invert the first two columns:

```
create index myindex on mytable(goal_id, year, target)
```

The base idea is that you want to put the more restrictive criteria first.

Comment: Use `goalid` first.

Comment: @TheImpaler: I was editing while you were commenting... Actually, it depends on how data is spread in the columns (eg if there are only two distinct `goalid`s and  `year` spread over 100 disctinct values, you want `year` first). OP did not share that information.

Comment: Does include `target` field into index give some performance improvement?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev: it does... that's the concept of *covering* index, which is explained in my answer).

Comment: Oh yes, it does. That's called a "covering index". It prevents MySQL's "dual index lookup" issue. Not needed, but if you need performance, do it.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for the tips! Creating the index reduced the query from 10s to 0.2s

Comment: No.  Put the `=` column first.  That way it will touch only consecutive rows in the index.

Comment: More on the cardinality wives' tale:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-range

Answer (score 2):

An index on `year`, `goal_id`, and `target`:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX index_name (goal_id, year, target)
```

As [Rick James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61264155/942774) has pointed out, `goal_id` needs to be first in the composite index, because it's matched with an `=`, followed by your range column `year`, then followed by what you want to retrieve, i.e. `target`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip!

Comment: No.  Put the `=` column first.  That way it will touch only consecutive rows in the index.  The cardinality of the individual columns does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is simple.  Thing(s) tested with `=` first.  Then do at most one "range".  (And `BETWEEN` is equivalent in performance to an equivalent pair of inequalities.)

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

And, as GMB points out, extending the index to make it covering gives another boost.  All the work is done in the index's BTree; no need to look in the data's BTree.  So, *in this order*:

```
INDEX(goal_id, year, target)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT target FROM table WHERE goal_id=1 AND year BETWEEN 2015 AND 2020

you may find faster query completion by referring to year only one time.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that query

Comment: No.  `BETWEEN` actually is turned into the other format when the statement is parsed or optimizer.  See `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...;  SHOW WARNINGS;`

Comment: @hubert Please post your SHOW CREATE TABLE table; for my own deeper analysis (we will all see your current table and index structure).  Rick James, Thank you for the details and your deeper knowledge of how things work in MySQL.