# What can I do to optimize my SQL query that applies to both Postgres and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, query-optimization

My table DDL is:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    active bool NULL DEFAULT true,
    created_at timestamp NULL,
    organization_id NULL,
    CONSTRAINT accounts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX index_accounts_on_active ON accounts USING btree (active);
CREATE INDEX index_accounts_on_created_at ON accounts USING btree (created_at);
CREATE INDEX index_accounts_on_organization_id ON accounts USING btree (organization_id);
```

My table has 200k records and my query is:

```
select count(*) from account where active = false and organization_id in (3,2,20,30,99,69) and created_at >= '2016-09-03 15:29:54.541924';
```

Explain analyze return this query plan:

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=5791.37..5791.38 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=36.504..36.504 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=5791.26..5791.37 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=36.411..38.788 rows=2 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 1
        Workers Launched: 1
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=4791.26..4791.27 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=31.313..31.313 rows=1 loops=2)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on accounts  (cost=0.00..4625.94 rows=66126 width=0) (actual time=0.073..26.518 rows=56057 loops=2)
                    Filter: ((NOT active) AND (created_at >= '2016-09-03 15:29:54.541924'::timestamp without time zone) AND (organization_id = ANY ('{3,2,20,30,99,69}'::integer[])))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 43943
Planning Time: 0.293 ms
Execution Time: 38.863 ms
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You have two answers. Which one provides the best performance?

Comment: You have two databases.  Which one are you actually using?

Comment: I am using Postgres at the moment but I'd like a solution that is compatible with both databases.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
select count(*)
from account
where active = false and
      organization_id in (3,2,20,30,99,69) and
      created_at >= '2016-09-03 15:29:54.541924';
```

I would recommend an index with three keys:  `(active, organization_id, created_at)`.

That said, the most efficient way to write the query across the two databases is probably:

```
select sum(cnt)
from ((select count(*) as cnt
       from account
       where active = false and
             organization_id = 3 and
             created_at >= '2016-09-03 15:29:54.541924'
      ) union all
      (select count(*) as cnt
       from account
       where active = false and
             organization_id = 2 and
             created_at >= '2016-09-03 15:29:54.541924'
      ) union all
      . . .
     ) a;
```

This can make full use of an index on `(active, organization_id, created_at)` or `(organization_id, active, created_at)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a composite index here to cover the entire `WHERE` clause.  The following should work on either database:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON account (organization_id, created_at, active);
```

I placed the more restrictive columns first, followed by least restrictive.  That is, I am assuming few records would match your restrictions on `organization_id`, while significantly more would match `active`.

Note that while you do have indices on the above three columns, they are in separate indices.  Most of the time (but not always), a database will choose to use only a single index to satisfy an execution plan.  This means that, e.g., Postgres would probably choose to use neither of your indices, because no single one covers the entire `WHERE` clause.

Comment: No.  Place the column(s) tested with `=` first.  That will cluster the information better.

Comment: @RickJames I don't know about mysql, but postgresql uses the leading organization_id just fine, jumping to the correct created_at offset within each in-list value.  (But due to the low selectivity, there is probably little point in doing it that way here).

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, I say

```
INDEX(active, organization_id, created_at),
INDEX(active, created_at, organization_id)
```

The Optimizer will look at the statistics to decide which is probably faster.

Each is "covering".  The optimizer will use the first two columns of the `INDEX` that it picks to do filtering, then finish off the filtering with the third column.

`active` must be first because it is tested with `=` and the other two are not.

Argument for `=` over "cardinality":  [Higher cardinality column first in an index when involving a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-range)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are visiting over half the rows:

```
(actual) rows=56057
Rows Removed by Filter: 43943
```

There is little reason to think any index is going to be extremely useful, compared to just doing the seq scan.