# What is the correct order for composite indexes (mysql)

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, composite-index

I've read that in composite indexes, you should order the columns with the most specific first, however my thought is that the most optimal route would be for least specific indexes to be covered first due to my understanding (or lack there of) on how mapping over indexes would work in memory. [visual aid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZkwP.png)

For example, if I have a table, `vehicles` with three columns, `vehicle`, `type` and `driver`.

`vehicle` can be filtered to 3 possible values `car`, `bike`, `helicopter`

`type` can be filtered to 6 values, `petrol/automatic`, `petrol/manual`, `diesel/automatic`, `diesel/manual`,, `electric/automatic`, `electric/manual`

`driver` is the driver's name (an indeterminate number of values)

--

If filtering by `vehicle` can return 1000 results, by `type` 500 results, and by `driver` say, 3 results, shouldn't the optimal index be `vehicle, type, driver` ? Because if the index is starts with `driver` wouldn't that mean scanning over a giant index before further filtering by `type` then `vehicle` ?

Could someone please clear this up for me, and explain to me, if I *should* order columns with the most specific first, why, and how it works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How important is the order of columns in indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292662/how-important-is-the-order-of-columns-in-indexes)

Answer (score 2):

- When testing all 3 columns for `=`, it does *not* matter what order they are in in the `INDEX` or in the `WHERE` clause.
- When testing some columns for `=` and some with range (`LIKE`, `BETWEEN`, etc), have the `=` columns first in the `INDEX`.  The index won't be used beyond the first range.
- When testing for 1 or 2 columns, those columns need to be first.

Because of those guidelines, you may find that different queries need different `INDEXes`.

More: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

and [Higher cardinality column first in an index when involving a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-range)

Another way to look at cardinality is that it applies only to the entire index, not the individual columns.  Poor selectivity will lead to the Optimizer not using the index, but scanning the table instead.

> If filtering by vehicle can return 1000 results, by type 500 results, and by driver say, 3 results

```
    WHERE vehicle = '...'  -- no index will be used
    WHERE type    = '...'  -- no index will be used
    WHERE driver  = '...'  -- INDEX(driver, ...) will be used
```

(Those assume that there is nothing else relevant in the `WHERE`.)

For this

```
    WHERE vehicle = '...'
      AND type    = '...'
      AND driver  = '...'
```

This is very useful:  `INDEX(vehicle, type, driver)`.  Furthermore, the `WHERE` clauses and the `INDEX` can be in different orders.

Comment: (I added some more while you were upvoting it.)