# MariaDB - why are the primary keys not being used for joins on a specific table?

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, mariadb, key

I'm trying to understand why these two queries are treated differently with regards to use of the primary keys in joins.

This query with a join on `icd_codes` (the `SELECT` query, without the `EXPLAIN`, of course) completes in 56 ms:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT var.Var_ID,
       var.Gene,
       var.HGVSc,
       pVCF_145K.PT_ID,
       pVCF_145K.AD_ALT,
       pVCF_145K.AD_REF,
       icd_codes.ICD_NM,
       icd_codes.PT_AGE
FROM public.variants_145K var
         INNER JOIN public.pVCF_145K USING (Var_ID)
         INNER JOIN public.icd_codes using (PT_ID)
#          INNER JOIN public.demographics USING (PT_ID)
WHERE Gene IN ('SLC9A6', 'SLC9A7')
  AND Canonical
  AND impact = 'high'
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys                                                    | key                             | key_len | ref                    | rows | Extra                              |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | var       | range | PRIMARY,variants_145K_Gene_index,variants_145K_Impact_Gene_index | variants_145K_Impact_Gene_index | 125     | NULL                   | 280  | Using index condition; Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pVCF_145K | ref   | PRIMARY,pVCF_145K_PT_ID_index                                    | PRIMARY                         | 326     | public.var.Var_ID      | 268  |                                    |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | icd_codes | ref   | PRIMARY                                                          | PRIMARY                         | 38      | public.pVCF_145K.PT_ID | 29   |                                    |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
```

This query with a join on `demographics` takes over 11 minutes, and I'm not sure how to interpret the difference in the explain results. Why is it resorting to using the join buffer? How can I optimize this further?

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT variants_145K.Var_ID,
       variants_145K.Gene,
       variants_145K.HGVSc,
       pVCF_145K.PT_ID,
       pVCF_145K.AD_ALT,
       pVCF_145K.AD_REF,
       demographics.Sex,
       demographics.Age
FROM public.variants_145K
         INNER JOIN public.pVCF_145K USING (Var_ID)
#          inner join public.icd_codes using (PT_ID)
         INNER JOIN public.demographics USING (PT_ID)
WHERE Gene IN ('SLC9A6', 'SLC9A7')
  AND Canonical
  AND impact = 'high'
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys                                                    | key                             | key_len | ref                                                   | rows    | Extra                              |
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | variants_145K | range  | PRIMARY,variants_145K_Gene_index,variants_145K_Impact_Gene_index | variants_145K_Impact_Gene_index | 125     | NULL                                                  | 280     | Using index condition; Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | demographics  | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                          | NULL                            | NULL    | NULL                                                  | 1916393 | Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pVCF_145K     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,pVCF_145K_PT_ID_index                                    | PRIMARY                         | 364     | public.variants_145K.Var_ID,public.demographics.PT_ID | 1       |                                    |
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+
```

Adding a further filter in `demographics` (`WHERE demographics.Platform IS NOT NULL`) as shown below reduces to 38 seconds. However, there are queries where we do not use such filters so it would be ideal if it could use the primary `PT_ID` key in the joins.

```
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys                                                    | key                             | key_len | ref                                                   | rows   | Extra                                                                  |
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | variants_145K | range  | PRIMARY,variants_145K_Gene_index,variants_145K_Impact_Gene_index | variants_145K_Impact_Gene_index | 125     | NULL                                                  | 280    | Using index condition; Using where                                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | demographics  | range  | PRIMARY,Demographics_PLATFORM_index                              | Demographics_PLATFORM_index     | 17      | NULL                                                  | 258544 | Using index condition; Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pVCF_145K     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,pVCF_145K_PT_ID_index                                    | PRIMARY                         | 364     | public.variants_145K.Var_ID,public.demographics.PT_ID | 1      |                                                                        |
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The tables:

```
create table public.demographics  # 1,916,393 rows
(
    PT_ID varchar(9) not null
        primary key,
    Age float(3,1) null,
    Status varchar(8) not null,
    Sex varchar(7) not null,
    Race_1 varchar(41) not null,
    Race_2 varchar(41) not null,
    Ethnicity varchar(22) not null,
    Smoker_flag tinyint(1) not null,
    Platform char(4) null,
    MyCode_Consent tinyint(1) not null,
    MR_ENC_DT date null,
    Birthday date null,
    Deathday date null,
    max_unrelated_145K tinyint unsigned null
);
create index Demographics_PLATFORM_index
    on public.demographics (Platform);

create table public.icd_codes  # 116,220,141 rows
(
    PT_ID varchar(9) not null,
    ICD_CD varchar(8) not null,
    ICD_NM varchar(217) not null,
    DX_DT date not null,
    PT_AGE float(3,1) unsigned not null,
    CODE_SYSTEM char(7) not null,
    primary key (PT_ID, ICD_CD, DX_DT)
);

create table public.pVCF_145K  # 10,113,244,082 rows
(
    Var_ID varchar(81) not null,
    PT_ID varchar(9) not null,
    GT tinyint unsigned not null,
    GQ smallint unsigned not null,
    AD_REF smallint unsigned not null,
    AD_ALT smallint unsigned not null,
    DP smallint unsigned not null,
    FT varchar(30) null,
    primary key (Var_ID, PT_ID)
);
create index pVCF_145K_PT_ID_index
    on public.pVCF_145K (PT_ID);

create table public.variants_145K  # 151,314,917 rows
(
    Var_ID varchar(81) not null,
    Gene varchar(22) null,
    Feature varchar(18) not null,
    Feature_type varchar(10) null,
    HIGH_INF_POS tinyint(1) null,
    Consequence varchar(26) not null,
    rsid varchar(34) null,
    Impact varchar(8) not null,
    Canonical tinyint(1) not null,
    Exon smallint unsigned null,
    Intron smallint unsigned null,
    HGVSc varchar(323) null,
    HGVSp varchar(196) null,
    AA_position smallint unsigned null,
    gnomAD_NFE_MAF float null,
    SIFT varchar(14) null,
    PolyPhen varchar(17) null,
    GHS_Hom mediumint(5) unsigned null,
    GHS_Het mediumint(5) unsigned null,
    GHS_WT mediumint(5) unsigned null,
    IDT_MAF float null,
    VCR_MAF float null,
    UKB_MAF float null,
    Chr tinyint unsigned not null,
    Pos int(9) unsigned not null,
    Ref varchar(298) not null,
    Alt varchar(306) not null,
    primary key (Var_ID, Feature)
);
create index variants_145K_Chr_Pos_Ref_Alt_index
    on public.variants_145K (Chr, Pos, Ref, Alt);

create index variants_145K_Gene_index
    on public.variants_145K (Gene);

create index variants_145K_Impact_Gene_index
    on public.variants_145K (Impact, Gene);

create index variants_145K_rsid_index
    on public.variants_145K (rsid);
```

This is on MariaDB 10.5.8 (innodb)

Thank you!

Comment: Add the definition of `variants_145K`

Answer (score 0):

`INDEX(impact, canonical, gene)` or `INDEX(canonical, impact, gene)` is better for the `var`.

If you don't need it, remove `INNER JOIN public.icd_codes USING (PT_ID)`.  It is costly to reach into that table, and all it does is filter out any rows that fail in the `JOIN`.

Ditto for `demographics`.

The "join buffer" is not always a "resort to"; however, it is often a fast way.  Especially if most of the table is needed and the join_buffer is big enough.

**More**

Note that `demographics` has a single-column `PRIMARY KEY(PT_ID)`, but the other table has a composite PK.  This probably impacts whether the Optimizer will even consider using the "join buffer".

Depending on a lot of things (in the query and the data), the Optimizer may make the wrong choice between join_buffer and repeatedly doing lookups.

Comment: Thank you! We often include other columns from the icd_codes and demographics tables in our queries; I just cut them out for brevity here since the problem was arising from the PT_ID key not being used on the demographics table join, whereas it is used in the icd_codes table join.


Why is (impact, gene) better? My thinking was that we often filter using gene without impact, whereas when we include impact filter it is always accompanied by gene as well.


My main point of confusion is, why is primary key PT_ID used in joining the icd_codes table, but not demographics?

Comment: @JonLuo - Since you also search on `gene` without `impact`, then have both `(impact, gene)` and `(gene)`.  Here's a related discussion (although `IN` is not quite the same as "range"):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-range/50240079#50240079

Comment: @JonLuo - and...  An the columns of an index are used Left to Right, no skipping.  If you need to skip, then the rest of the index is not useful (for the query in question).

Comment: @JonLuo - and...  for your final question, I added to my Answer.

Comment: Thanks Rick, will change the index to `(impact, gene)`. How would you recommend to optimize joins on `demographics`? The example query with `icd_codes` completes in 56ms, whereas the query with `demographics` takes ~11 minutes. I wonder if this is something caused by updating from MariaDB 10.3 to 10.5... similar queries with `demographics` were very quick in the past.

Comment: Please change the queries (or, better yet) start a new question that shows the use of demographics.  There are too many possible variants; I may not hit on the right answer for your 11m query.

Comment: @JonLuo - Also, please provide an estimate of the size of each table.  It smells like they are well into the millions.

Comment: Updated with specific queries tested, updated execution plans with the new index, and table row counts.

Comment: Oops, I missed `canonical`; have changed my `INDEX` recommendation`.  Please see if the change made any difference before I dig deeper.

Comment: @JonLuo - and.... I don't see `platform` in `demographics`.  But it might be beneficial to have `INDEX(platform, PT_ID)`.

Comment: Oops, sorry, fixed the `demographics` DDL. I had a single `INDEX(Platform)` on `demographics`. I just tried replacing it with `INDEX(platform, PT_ID)` and got the same 38 seconds. If we don't always use `var.canonical`, does that mean I should keep the current `INDEX(impact, gene)` and also add a `INDEX(impact, canonical, gene)`?