# Can I have multi-order index for composite/multi-column index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, composite-index

I have an `invoices` table like this:

```
| id   | client_id | is_recurring |
|----- |-----------| -------------|
| 1    | 2121      | 0            |
| 2    | 7434      | 1            |
```

Now throughout my application, I might have following queries:

```
select * from invoices where client_id = 2121 and is_recurring = 0;
```

or

```
select * from invoices where is_recurring = 0 and client_id = 2121;
```

or any other order of where clause.

I already have index on client_id an is_recurring separately.

But for composite index, should I create composite index on

```
compost_index('client_id','is_recurring')
```

or

```
compost_index('is_recurring','client_id')
```

**or Both?**

Note that both are in different order. So for performance of different order searches? should I created composite index with multiple order/direction?

**Update:**
Also if I have a `date` column which I will use for comparing greater or less or order by, what combinations of composite indexes I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rough rule of thumb, you might expect better performance in a two column index by placing the more restrictive (higher cardinality) column first.  So, I would suggest:

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON invoices compost_index (client_id, is_recurring)
```

This index, if used, would let MySQL discard a large portion of the index just by filtering by the `client_id`.  The `is_recurring` column, on the other hand, presumably only takes on the two values of 0 and 1.  So, filtering by this might not allow for many records to be discarded when scanning the index.

Comment: No.  Cardinality does not determine the order in a composite index.  Proof: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-range

Comment: @Tim check the updated question also

Answer (score 1):

Either WHERE order;
Either INDEX order - regardless of cardinality; see [*proof*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-range)
That is, *either* `WHERE` is handled equally well by *either* `INDEX`.
Neither single-column index - They may get in the way.

Meanwhile, the composite index also handles the corresponding single-column need.  That is, `INDEX(a,b)` takes care of cases where `INDEX(a)` is needed, but not where `INDEX(b)` is needed.

For this:

```
 where client_id = 2121 and is_recurring = 0 and date > '2021-04-28';
```

a new rule is used:

```
INDEX(client_id, is_recurring,  -- in either order
      date)                     -- then the range test
```

That is, put all columns tested with `=` (or `IS NULL`) first; then you get one chance to add a range test.

```
where client_id = 2121 and date > '2021-04-28' -- (client_id, date)
where client_id = 2121 order by date > '2021-04-28'
          -- also (client_id, date), but now the order is required
where client_id = 2121
  and date > '2021-04-28'
  order by date    -- again (client_id, date), specific ordering
where client_id = 2121
  and is_recurring = 0
  and date > '2021-04-28';  -- back to the 3-column one above
```

An `=` test is one thing; all inequality tests are "range".

More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: So for 'b', I need to declare individual index also? Also check the updated question also

Comment: @JaberAlNahian - I think I have now answered even the versions you deleted.