# Why explain SELECT shows different index name in "key" field?

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

I have products table with several indexes and products_published_at_category_id_regular_price_status_index with 4 fields

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creator_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('D','P','A','I') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'D' COMMENT ' D => Draft, P=>Pending Review, A=>Active, I=>Inactive',
  `slug` varchar(260) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `city_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `regular_price` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sale_price` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `in_stock` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stock_qty` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `has_discount_price` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_featured` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `short_description` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `published_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `products_creator_id_title_index` (`creator_id`,`title`),
  UNIQUE KEY `products_slug_unique` (`slug`),
  KEY `products_category_id_foreign` (`category_id`),
  KEY `products_city_id_foreign` (`city_id`),
  KEY `products_published_at_category_id_regular_price_status_index` (`published_at`,`category_id`,`regular_price`,`status`),
  KEY `products_published_category_sale_price_status_discount_index` (`published_at`,`category_id`,`sale_price`,`status`,`has_discount_price`),
  KEY `products_title_status_index` (`title`,`status`),
  KEY `products_published_at_title_status_index` (`published_at`,`title`,`status`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `products_city_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `cities` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `products_creator_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`creator_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

But running sql with these 4 parameters in sql statement and looking at explain

```
 explain format =json  SELECT *
    FROM `products`
    WHERE products.published_at >'2022-04-01'
      AND products.published_at <='2022-04-21'
      AND `products`.`category_id` = '6'
      AND `products`.`status` = 'A'
    ORDER BY `regular_price` asc
```

I see "products_category_id_foreign" in "key" value, but not "products_published_at_category_id_regular_price_status_index" as I expected :

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "107.90"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": true,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "products",
        "access_type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": [
          "products_category_id_foreign",
          "products_published_at_category_id_regular_price_status_index",
          "products_published_category_sale_price_status_discount_index",
          "products_published_at_title_status_index"
        ],
        "key": "products_category_id_foreign",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "category_id"
        ],
        "key_length": "2",
        "ref": [
          "const"
        ],
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 122,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 4,
        "filtered": "3.79",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "95.70",
          "eval_cost": "0.46",
          "prefix_cost": "107.90",
          "data_read_per_join": "11K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "creator_id",
          "title",
          "status",
          "slug",
          "sku",
          "category_id",
          "city_id",
          "regular_price",
          "sale_price",
          "in_stock",
          "stock_qty",
          "has_discount_price",
          "is_featured",
          "short_description",
          "description",
          "published_at",
          "created_at",
          "updated_at"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "((`BiCurrencies`.`products`.`published_at` > TIMESTAMP'2022-04-01 00:00:00') and (`BiCurrencies`.`products`.`published_at` <= TIMESTAMP'2022-04-21 00:00:00') and (`BiCurrencies`.`products`.`status` = 'A'))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And

```
"used_key_parts=  [                    "category_id"                 ],
```

...

So explain seems not good

Also I see that values in "query_cost" and "cost_info" are high.
I suppose these are some internal mysql values and they must be as small as possible.
I tried to run commands :

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE products;
ANALYZE TABLE products;
```

before running my sql statement - but results were the same...

Version mysqlnd 8.1.4 under kubuntu 20

**UPDATED PART 1:**

Thanks!

1. From my prior expierence when I create index on several fields I followed next rule:
   at left side must be fields with biggest number of set. In my case sure that is published_at.

At right side must be status (enum of 4 possible values)

category_id - has about 10 possible values.

field published_at can also be used in “=” comparison, alos in “>=”/"<". To create different indexes for different cases?
2) trying to delete key products_category_id_foreign with command :

```
alter TABLE `products` drop key products_category_id_foreign;
```

I got error :

```
SQL Error [1553] [HY000]: Cannot drop index 'products_category_id_foreign': needed in a foreign key constraint
```

This is reference to other table...

3. Can In in mysql request set preferable index? Actually I use laravel eloquent library?

**UPDATED PART 2 :**

1. I moved published_at into the end of my filter and after database rebuild
   the index I need is applied.
   As for “an old myth". Yes, looks like that is true. Before accepyting your answer, could you please give a ref to
   working rules as for mysql 5.x/8.x ?
   I have read some docs(including official mysql docs), but I did not read such rule.
2. As for the error message, when I try to remove products_category_id_foreign : I use laravel migration with eloquent
   and products_category_id_foreign is created automatically with command :

   $table->unsignedSmallInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
   $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');

So I do not see how can I remove this index. But seems that is not issue as I managed to use valid index.

Thanks!

Comment: As you have only 122 rows in your table, it seems that MySql is not even going to use any index for your query. It does not need it. Try to upload 100K rows and see what happens

Comment: Thanks! Now I am on dev stage only and have few of data. How can I set index in sql request as "key" index name?

Comment: With factory I added 200 000 rows, and run OPTIMIZE TABLE products;
ANALYZE TABLE products;
 after that. But  I still have  "key" = "products_category_id_foreign". What is wrong ?

Comment: Change the order of the columns in your index, put first the category and then the published_at

Comment: i changed order and set `products`.`category_id` = '6'  at first order , but the same results : Index lookup on products using products_category_id_foreign . Also I supposed that I had in my sql where part to set where conditions similar my index fields from left to right. Is it good rule? If now please link to relative example

Comment: You have encountered an old myth.  Cardinality is _not_ relevant for individual components in a composite index.  What _is important_ is whether the column will be tested with "=" or not.  (We could discuss how an index is laid out in order to understand it.)

Comment: As for the error message, had you already added the new composite index? I wonder if ADD needs to be done before DROP (or in the same ALTER).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE products.published_at >'2022-04-01'
  AND products.published_at <='2022-04-21'
  AND `products`.`category_id` = '6'
  AND `products`.`status` = 'A'
```

Putting a "range" firsts is usually counter-productive; move it to last, after all the "=" tests:

```
INDEX(category_id, status, published_at)
```

and Drop any indexes that match the beginning of this index, namely

```
KEY `products_category_id_foreign` (`category_id`),
```

A side note:  "midnight" is usually thought of as the start pf a day:

```
WHERE products.published_at >= '2022-04-01'
  AND products.published_at  < '2022-04-21'
```

Re Update 2:

- Reference manuals focus on what *can* be done.  I focus on what *should* be done.  Hence, I don't think the ref manual has the info.
- A B+Tree (which InnoDB uses for indexes and for the data) can efficiently scan through "consecutive" entries.
- As a thought exercise, think of a composite index as the column values concatenated together, then sorted into a B+Tree.  That leads to my advice of putting all `=` tested columns first, followed by one "range" test (`published_at`).
- Not quite addressing the "old myth":  [Higher cardinality column first in an index when involving a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-range)
- See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1
- Adding/removing indexes:  See ref manual about `ALTER TABLE ... ADD INDEX` and `DROP INDEX`.  Perhaps the `FOREIGN KEY` is getting in the way.
- Don't get me started on how frameworks require to learn about databases twice -- once for the framework's view of data and another time for the underlying engine's view (MySQL).

Comment: Please look at UPDATED PART 1

Comment: @mstdmstd - I added 2 Comments.

Comment: Thanks! Please look at UPDATED PART 2

Comment: @mstdmstd - I added to my Answer to partially address your part 2.