# Adding a third column in an index and order of the columns for efficient queries

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `CustomerRatings` (
  `movie_id` int NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int NOT NULL,
  `customer_score` double NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                 
  `num_of_theaters` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`,`category_id`)
)
```

I'd like to be able to do efficient queries having `num_of_theaters` as part of the `WHERE` condition (along with movie_id and category_id).
I think that if I add a new index as follows:

```
`KEY (`movie_id`,`category_id`,`num_of_theaters`)
```

that should help but I am not sure if the cardinality of the columns matter in this case.
The `category_id` has much lower cardinality (very small range of values) than `num_of_theaters`. Would that affect the index and should the order of the cols in the index definition be different? Or is there another more efficient approach?

**Note:** In case it matters the most common condition would be `num_of_theaters > 0` or `num_of_theaters <> 0`

Comment: *I'd like to be able to do efficient queries having num_of_theaters as part of the WHERE condition* , then the index will not be used https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html#:~:text=MySQL%20can%20use%20multiple%2Dcolumn,three%20columns%2C%20and%20so%20on.

Comment: @ErgestBasha: Why it won't be used? The way I read the highlighted statement I understand it is used. What am I messing up on this? Is it because it is similar to PK index?

Comment: at the page a linked you have a detailed explanation. The order of columns in the index matter

Comment: Why `DOUBLE`?  It sounds like an integral value.  Furthermore, it sounds like a non-negative value.

Comment: We _must_ see the rest of the query -- it matters whether you are saying `movie_id=123` or `movie_id IN (...)` or `movie_id > 0`  The answer may be different in each case!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-range